# How to fix the installation path for application in deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, path

Please tell me how can i fix the installation path of my application on client machine so that my application should not tell user to enter/select path for installation and my application get installed on default path.. i am using c#.net and .net deployment tool

Comment: are you using visual studio for creating setup?

Comment: @anishmarokey- Yes i am using visual studio for creating setup

Answer (score 1):

You just have to erase the installation folder interface in VSTO User Interface View on your setup project.